# Difference between Health and Damage Absorption in War of the Roses

Tags: war-of-the-roses

For weapons, what's the difference between Health and Damage Absorption?

Answer (score 1):

Health absorption:

- This allows the player to heal faster from both yourself and others. The higher the absorption the quicker it is to reach maximum health.

Damage absorption:

- This allows the player to absorb damage. Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Per definition, "absorption" doesn't mean the same as "regeneration". Yet another false answer, eh?